# .NET Attachable Profiler

Tags: .net, profiling, profiler

Is there any process-attachable .NET profiler available?

The problem faced is that I am currently wanting to profile an online-only ClickOnce application, which cannot be started any other way other than the website. Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/.net/profiler/index.jsp)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) + [sos extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) as well. It can be attached to a process.

Answer (score 1):

ProfileSharp is an open source .NET code profiler which can attach to a process.
However it is not tested for profiling applications with versions above .NET 2.0

Here is the code : 
http://www.koders.com/info.aspx?c=ProjectInfo&pid=EVXCMGMDSWZ1GSY2RW1EFHVF3A
[Not yet hosted on github or sourceforge but should be there any time sooner]

If you can look at the code and update it, you can make it work for applications built with versions above .NET 2.0

[Hint: I am on the ProfileSharp Team]

Answer (score 0):

Try [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979205.aspx) by Microsoft. [Free Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=A362781C-3870-43BE-8926-862B40AA0CD0&displaylang=en).